# Closing old accepted questions

Tags: discussion

Please refrain from marking as closed 3 year old questions with answers.

This question is a decent example: [change block call order in checkout](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/8890/change-block-call-order-in-checkout)

It makes the moderation queue difficult to sift through. Let's focus on **answering current questions**.  If you feel something is [egregious](https://www.google.com/search?q=egregious), however, please *flag* for moderators instead of close voting.

Comment: To clarify why flags are preferable: close votes can pile on without a feedback loop. A moderator or the team of mods can make the decision to close or, more appropriately for old questions, flag them as off topic but retained for historical value.

Comment: Phil thx  for noticed this.. We should more care about close vote

Comment: Personally in future i will more care full about close vote

Comment: So @philwinkle for old questions with no answers at all, that do not seem to be answerable, it is still OK to raise a close flag in your opinion?

Comment: @7ochem that sounds fine

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well I reckon I'm faulty on this one.

Whenever I see people talking about a module provider (in this case it was ebizmarts) I always search for questions regarding this module provider and I mark them for closing.

I felt like it was a good thing to do for off topic questions that went through the moderators' net. I didn't think it was bad to do it for answered questions. Apologies

Comment: It was good for M2EE questions which had zero answers. For historical questions with answers, best to leave it alone.

Comment: @philwinkle thanks for enlightening me I'll be more careful from now